# How to prefill WordPress registration with social details

Tags: login, user-registration, social-connect

I created custom registration process in WordPress with a lot of extra fields like first name, last name etc.

I would like to make integration with Facebook/LinkedIn so first name, last name, email, fields are be prefilled with Facebook/LinkedIn, but still, users will need to enter other fields to finish registration.

Is it possible to do something like that, or is there some plugin which is doing that?

Comment: There is no need create a custom registration page in that case. You can use the following services: 
- https://oauth.net or https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/protocol/CAS-Protocol-Specification.html

You will then be required to write your own script to fetch the data from each user's Facebook profile. There are several plugins that already accomplish these, you can have a look and see what you can find.

Comment: sorry i am 3 years to late, but in case someone searches for this [Social Login - with Wordpress and Buddypress](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/oa-social-login/)

Comment: This question is about the Facebook/LinkedIn API, not about WP.

Comment: For LinkedIn, there is a plugin:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins Others probably have similar code for their services.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Auth0 plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/auth0/

oAuth plugins should auto populate the data that your API call allows. And your users should be able to edit their profiles also.

LinkedIn also has an AutoFill function here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/autofill-plugin